# SetValue test succeeds with my Period class but fails with my Name class

Tags: c#, testing, get, set, assert

So my first TestMethod went through, as expected. I tested my `SetValue` method.

```
p1 = new DateTimePeriod { From = DateTime.MinValue, To = DateTime.MaxValue };
p2 = new DateTimePeriod { From = DateTime.MaxValue, To = DateTime.MinValue };

[TestMethod]
public void SetPeriodTest()
{
   b.SetValue(ref p1, p2);
   Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.MaxValue, p1.From);
   Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.MinValue, p1.To);
}
```

But the next test fails. Apparently `x.AName`, `x.Valid` and `x.Id` are null although I clearly set them the same way I set `p1.From` and `p1.To`. Why are these properties returning null?

```
[TestMethod]
public void SetNameTest()
{
    var x = new Name { AName = "Jack", Valid = p1, Id = "123" };
    var y = new Name { AName = "John", Valid = p2, Id = "321" };
    b.SetValue(ref x, y);
    Assert.AreEqual("John", x.AName);
    Assert.AreEqual(p2, x.Valid);
    Assert.AreEqual("321", x.Id);
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class Name: Base
{
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { SetValue(ref id, value); }
    }
    private string aName;
    public string AName
    {
        get { return aName; }
        set { SetValue(ref aName, value); }
    }
    private DateTimePeriod valid;
    public DateTimePeriod Valid
    {
        get { return valid; }
        set { SetValue(ref valid, value); }
    }
}

public class DateTimePeriod: Period<DateTime>
{
}

public class Period<T>: Base
{
    private T from;
    private T to;
    public Period()
    {
        from = default(T);
        to = default(T);
    }
    public T From
    {
        get { return from; }
        set { SetValue(ref from, value); }
    }
    public T To
    {
        get { return to; }
        set { SetValue(ref to, value); }
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
public class Base: object
{
    public void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value)
    {
        if (field == null) return;
        if (field.Equals(value)) return;
        field = value;
        DoOnChanged();
    }
    public event EventHandler OnChanged;
    protected void DoOnChanged()
    {
        if (OnChanged == null) return;
        OnChanged(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: is only x.AName and so on null or y also ?

Comment: both are null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I debug your Code in the Unit test, it´s working without any Problems. I changed the setter to a normal use, because I don´t know what you are using for `Base` and `SetValue`.

But the Unit Test are working fine with this code:

```
namespace SampleUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Foo
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Bar()
        {
            var p1 = new DateTimePeriod { From = DateTime.MinValue, To = DateTime.MaxValue };
            var p2 = new DateTimePeriod { From = DateTime.MaxValue, To = DateTime.MinValue };
            var x = new Name { AName = "Jack", Valid = p1, Id = "123" };
            var y = new Name { AName = "John", Valid = p2, Id = "321" };
            Assert.AreEqual("John", x.AName);
            Assert.AreEqual(p2, x.Valid);
            Assert.AreEqual("321", x.Id);
        }
    } 

    public class Name
    {
        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private string aName;
        public string AName
        {
            get { return aName; }
            set { aName = value; ; }
        }
        private DateTimePeriod valid;
        public DateTimePeriod Valid
        {
            get { return valid; }
            set { valid = value ; }
        }
    }

    public class DateTimePeriod : Period<DateTime>
    {
    }

    public class Period<T>
    {
        private T from;
        private T to;
        public Period()
        {
            from = default(T);
            to = default(T);
        }
        public T From
        {
            get { return from; }
            set { from = value; }
        }
        public T To
        {
            get { return to; }
            set { to = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the `SetValue` is also the reason why your `DateTime` is working and your other classes don´t.

Comment: I have them initialized. They are actually located in [TestInitialize] but the code does not work with AName and Id also.

Comment: Can you post your full testmethod ?

Comment: It's the same as your answer basically. I'm having trouble with understanding why DateTimePeriod (contains DateTime values) works but Name (contains Strings and DateTime) does not. Class using different types does not allow me to give property values, but class using only DateTime values is working perfectly.

Comment: I thought you say x and y are null ? can you please add your structs/classes whatever for a minimal functional code example to test it.

Comment: Added the Name and DateTimePeriod class. No, x and y are Name class instances, but x.AName, x.Valid and x.Id are null for some reason. But p1.From and p1.To are not null.

Comment: Edited the answer, I don´t find an error, expect the SetValue methods, I don´t know what you do with them ?

Comment: If you look at SetPeriodTest ... the SetValue changes the values of p1 to p2 values. Your Bar TestMethod does not change any x values to y values and the test therefore fails. But the problem is that if I set x.AName value from "Jack" to "John", it does not actually change anything. It's telling me that x.AName is null and y.AName is null as well. But in my eyes I have properly declared them, just like in SetPeriodTest.

Comment: Well, can you post the SetValue-Method, without it the code is functional and without knowing the implementation its like gues who, without question =P

Comment: Alright I uploaded it, but I think I found the mistake, I don't know how that got there :S. if (field == null) return; Should be if (value== null) return;

Comment: Thanks for the help and effort you put into this though :)